# How to know the data type of a value of a sum type

Tags: haskell

Say I have such sum type

```
data YesOrNo = Yes | No
```

If somehow I have a value of this type in GHCI

```
>:t yOrN
yOrN :: YesOrNo
```

Is it possible to get the data type of this value so that I know if it's a Yes or a No?

Context:

I'm using a library that returns a sum type of 10+ types
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.3.2.3/docs/Data-Bson.html#t:Value

Now I have a value of this type, I would like to know which data type exactly is that value.

Comment: You may check with a function like `Data.Bool.bool No Yes . (Yes ==)`

Comment: The data type is `YesOrNo`, as reported by ghci. You want to know which constructor was used, which you can do by pattern matching.

Comment: `Yes` and `No` are not types, but values. Use `case yOrN of Yes -> ... ; No -> ....` to check the value, or other forms of pattern matching.